# Oneliner for SVN adding files inside unversioned subfolders

Tags: file, svn, directory, addition, versioning

I have files that i want to add to svn that are inside a number of nested sub folders. All the subfolder tree is still unversioned. 
Say i want to version file1 and file2 (but not file 3) inside subsubfolder and no other file inside subfolder (i.e. file0).
The current filesystem is as follows

```
trunk
|--subfolder
   |--file0
   |--subsubfolder
      |--file1
      |--file2
      |--file3
```

Trunk is versioned, subfolder and subsubfolder are not versioned.

```
    svn add /subfolder/subsubfolder/file1
```

gives

```
    svn: warning: W155010: The node 'trunk/subfolder/subsubfolder' was not found.

    svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist

    svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

I wonder if there is a quick, potentially one-liner, command to add those files instead of going through adding all the subfolders along the way (without adding their content) and then finally adding the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`--parents`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.parents) option. Here is an example:

`svn add --parents /subfolder/subsubfolder/file1`